# How to properly call identical functions in different schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the same function in multiple schemas. When I first call the function in schema A, subsequent calls will return data from schema A, regardless of how I call the function.

First call:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_a.my_little_function();
-> data from schema_a
```

Next call:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_b.my_little_function();
-> data from schema_a
```

When I set search_path to another schema that schema will stick.

```
SET SEARCH_PATH = 'schema_b';
SELECT * FROM schema_a.my_little_function();
-> data from schema_b
```

This happens across sessions. Anyone know what is going on?

The simplified function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_bla (id_param integer) RETURNS TABLE(data text)
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
SELECT t.data FROM table t;
$$
```

Comment: You didn't show us the code of the functions, but I assume the functions use un-qualified table names, so they use the one first on the search path

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. Is there any way I can avoid using fully qualified table names? Can I prefix the table names with the schema name the functions are called from? The functions are generated and that would make things much easier.

Comment: You can set the search path for the function in the function declaration

Comment: But wouldn't that mean I have to change the function declaration for each schema?

Comment: @JosephTura it would, but you can do it using dynamic SQL easily.

Comment: And there is no way to dynamically identify the name of the schema the function is defined in and just use that?

Comment: If you have your function set to a certain `search_path`, the table(s) will be looked for there if not schema specified. I think changing your functions once is easier that using some dynamic SQL to do (otherwise simple) operations.